# How to run ActiveMQ in a OSGi Felix container?

Tags: osgi, activemq-classic

Hi I would like run ActiveMQ inside the Apache Felix OSGi container. I don't want to run it as an embedded broker, in other words I don't want to have to write code. The ideal situation would be just to deploy the AMQ jars inside Felix and change config files to modify its behavior.

It looks like this is posible with the Apache Karaf container, but I cannot find neither documentation on how to do it in felix nor a clear answer if this is possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are looking for [Apache Service Mix](http://servicemix.apache.org/)

= Apache Karaf with ActiveMQ + Apache Camel + Apache CXF + other nice stuff.

But if you rather do it yourself, you could stick with Karaf or Felix, can't you just take the ActiveMQ bundle and do it similar to this instruction?

http://activemq.apache.org/osgi-integration.html

Comment: actually there are "features" available for Karaf that makes it real simple to install. So I would stick to Karaf using Felix as my OSGi Runtime.

Comment: Yes, true. Or simply use Service Mix as I said, since AMQ is pre installed. even easier.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The thing is that currently all our components are deployed in felix, I wouldn't like to introduce a new container (even when Karaf is on top of felix), since this will affect the standard way we set up different enviroments, (dev, qa, prod).

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to deploy ActiveMQ in pure Apache Felix then the best way to start is to look into the Karaf feature for ActiveMQ. You need to install all the bundles referenced there and some basic karaf bundles.

In the ActiveMQ Karaf feature the broker is started using a Spring or Blueprint deployer from Karaf. This will look for spring dm or blueprint files and start them. The broker config is then such a file that starts the whole ActiveMQ.

So with some effort it should be possible but in the end you will duplicate a lot functionality of karaf. So using Karaf in the first place like Petter suggests is the simpler way to go.

Comment: Thanks Christian. I really want it running in felix since all our systems currently are deployed there. Basically we just install bundles in felix and configure them for different environment types. It is not desirable to use a different container, meaning a different way to deploy AMQ.